# Another Arduino Programmer trying learn to control Blender

Tags: python, scripting

I need help with a try with Blender3D, I'm using the Blender 3.4.1 and I need change the text of the Text Object using Arduino.

I created at Arduino a simple code to send a Number to Serial, and at Blender I searched on the Internet and make this code...

arduino part:

```c
/*
Another Ordinary test 
*/
int x=10; // a simple number...
bool direction; // increase number or decrease 

void setup() {
 //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
 Serial.begin(9600);
 while (!Serial) {
   ;  // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
 }

 // prints title with ending line break
 Serial.println("Testing!");
 delay(1000);
 direction=true;  
}

void loop() {
 if (direction) 
 {x++;
  if (x >80) direction=false;
 } 
 else 
 { x--;
   if (x<11) direction=true;
 } 
 Serial.println("Next item: "+String(x)); // Print the String
 delay(2100); // Dramatic Pause 
}
```

into Blender I create a Text and created this example code:

```py
serialport = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1', 9600)
obj = bpy.context.object
curve_text = obj.data
print('Texto atual eh ')
print(curve_text.body)

for i in range(1, 10):
    x = serialport.readline()
    print(x)
    curve_text.body = str(x)
else:
    serialport.close()
print('Finished!')
serialport.close()
```

This is a print of the Blender:
[image]

The question is:

1. Why I cannot see any update of the Text, just when the Script is finished?
2. Why I see b' text \r\n' if I used str?

an Update: After the hint from @markus-von-broady, I fixed the Str problem.

Now about the update, the Blender3d Stop Respond until the script Finishes... Here a gif:

[image: Gif showing the problem of the update. I'm using Linux. I used the program peek to create this picture.]

Comment: I'm using Blender on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: It's not clear how you test your project: you say you don't see the update of the text, but also you say you see the text `b' text \r\n'`. So you see the update, just not immediately? Or do you test your code in two separate circumstances, in which the problems arise separately? The first problem might come into a need to refresh viewport, or update view layer. The second is about the bytes being converted to a string in this way by default - use `encode` function instead.

Comment: About the update, The blender stop to respond until the script finishes, so I can see only the last result. 
What I need to see a refresh of the viewport?

Comment: About the String... Thanks for your feedback! 
After your hint, I found the solution for the byte string here:

```python
curve_text.body = x.decode('utf-8')
```
Now I need fix the refresh problem...